# When to use id and when to not use id, when getting an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

is quite a sometime that I program in html and something that I'm trying to understand is when to use IDs.

I know that ID is unique and it is useful to get the element very simply in JavaScript, but when is it better to use a getElementById("ID") and when is better to not put an ID in the html file and use querySelector("something").

To make my question a little more clear, is getElementById("ID") always faster and with less complexity than any other way to retrive the same block, so I just put it everywhere makes sense and use it; or, for example, if i have a  div with an ID and i want to get his child is better to use getElementById("ID").children?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: That’s a preference for a developer. Most say never, some say whenever. I don’t use IDs in 99.9% of use cases because a class will do.

Comment: I'd almost always use an ID - more for readability than speed, but I suspect there's a speed advantage too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always more convenient to use `getElementById("***")` because it is faster and more specific, rather than using for example `querySelector("***")` or `getElementsByName("***")` which tend to need more details.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are more straight forward and require less code, and can be much faster depending on the structure of the document and your query, i also find it more readable to select elements by ID when it is only a single element that i was to deal with, as with classes it is more for a collection of similar items.